# Backbone and Rails 3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, coffeescript, railscasts

I am developing an application and I am following this rails cast:
 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1

Everything seems correct except that I keep receiving an error when I run my js console at localhost:3000 I get the following:

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined     posts_index.js:16
   Voice.Views.PostsIndex.PostsIndex.initialize                 posts_index.js:16
   Backbone.View                                                backbone.js:1147
   PostsIndex                                                   posts_index.js:10 
   Voice.Routers.Posts.Posts.index                              posts_router.js:24
   (anonymous function)                                         backbone.js:900
   (anonymous function)                                         backbone.js:1081
   _.some._.any                                                 underscore.js:209
   _.extend.loadUrl                                             backbone.js:1079
   _.extend.start                                               backbone.js:1046
   window.Voice.initialize                                      voice.js:10
   (anonymous function)                                         voice.js:15
   fire                                                         jquery.js:975
   self.fireWith                                                jquery.js:1083
  jQuery.extend.ready                                           jquery.js:407
  DOMContentLoaded                                              jquery.js:84
```

Here is my backbone Code for the collections, models, views, routers and templates:

### app/assets/javascripts/voice.js.coffee

```
Window.Voice =
    Models: {}
    Collections: {}
    Views: {}
    Routers: {}
    initialize: ->
            new Voice.Routers.Posts()
            Backbone.history.start()
$(document).ready ->
    Voice.initialize()
```

### app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require voice
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./collections
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./routers
//= require_tree .
```

### javascripts/routers/posts_router.js.coffee

```
class Voice.Routers.Posts extends Backbone.Router
    routes:
            '': 'index'
    initialize: ->
            @collection = new Voice.Collections.Posts()
            @collection.fetch()
    index: ->
            view = new Voice.Views.PostsIndex()
            $('#container').html(view.render().el)
```

### javascripts/views/posts/posts_index.js.coffee

```
class Voice.Views.PostsIndex extends Backbone.View

    template: JST['posts/index']

    initialize: ->
            @collection.on('reset', @render, this)

    render: ->
            $(@el).html(@template(posts: @collection))
            this
```

### app/assets/templates/posts/index.jst.eco

```
<h1> BACKBONE WORKS</h1>
<tr><td>
<%= @posts %>
</td></tr>
```

### javascripts/collections/posts.js.coffee

```
class Voice.Collections.Posts extends Backbone.Collection
    url: '/api/posts'
    model: Voice.Models.Post
```

### javascripts/models/post.js.coffee

```
class Voice.Models.Post extends Backbone.Model
```

### config/routes.rb

```
Voice::Application.routes.draw do
    match '/login' => 'session#create'
    get 'logout', to: 'session#destroy', as: 'logout'
    resources :users
    scope "api" do
            resources :posts
    end
root :to => "main#index"
end
```

### controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :json => Post.all
  end

  def show
    render :json => Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def upvote
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    current_user.like(@post)
    render :json => @post
  end

  def downvote
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    current_user.dislike(@post)
    render :json => @post
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.create!(:content => params[:content])
    render :json => @post
  end
end
```

### app/views/main/index.html.erb

```
<table class = 'table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover'>
        <div id='container'>
        </div>
</table>
```

Backbone is hard to debug and I have already put in 12 hours + into it. Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PostsIndex` does this:

```
initialize: ->
    @collection.on('reset', @render, this)
```

but you're instantiating it like this:

```
class Voice.Routers.Posts extends Backbone.Router
    #...
    index: ->
        view = new Voice.Views.PostsIndex()
```

I think you want to pass the router's `@collection` to the `PostsIndex`:

```
view = new Voice.Views.PostsIndex(collection: @collection)
```

Backbone will [automatically convert that `collection` option to `@collection`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) inside `PostsIndex`:

> **constructor / initialize** `new View([options])`
>
> [...] There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName` and `attributes`.

so just including `collection: @collection` when constructing the `PostsIndex` is sufficient.